# Python: Multi platform multi processing 2.4

Tags: python, cross-platform, multiprocessing

I have to write a python application that has to run with python 2.4 for Unix and 2.7 for Windows.
This application must run parallel tasks that will synchronize and have to share message between them.

What would be the best, most simple, reliable and lightweight solution to do that?

I found a library that uses `os.fork()` but unfortunately `os.fork()` is not windows compatible.
The `multiprocess` package is not python 2.4 compatible.

I think the only solution left is `subprocess` but I was wondering if there was another solution to solve my problem.

Comment: I would suggest not using python 2.4 any more, it's officially out of support

Comment: I wish I could :) But it's actually a requirement as CentOS 5 is using python 2.4 :(

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Threads](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) it may be easier.  There's a practical guide [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/).

The guide also has examples on using [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html)'s with threads.

Using queues you can pass messages between the threads.

Threads are lighter than creating a new process, and should be cross platform, and it looks like they're in python version 2.4.  This [guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) I think was written for 2.4

Comment: Threads in python will not run in parallel because of the GIL.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but I would rather not use multithreading as I want my process to be independants if one crashes for any reason, I don't want my whole application to crash.

Comment: @g19fanatic: actually they can run in parallel. Blocking IO operations release GIL, C extensions can release GIL. Even if GIL is not released threads run concurrently (though no speed benefits in this case). There is not enough info in the question to suggest that GIL would be a problem.

Comment: @user1724384: Most errors in Python are exceptions which you can catch. Crashes (due to bug in python or C extension module) are relatively rare. btw, there is a [backport of multiprocessing to Python 2.4](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/multiprocessing/2.6.2.1)